# Change state in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs, addeventlistener, setstate

How can I change state on click event on the buttons? Now I have error

**Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function**

I know that I can't use here **this.setState** but I can't understand where should I make bind

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {opened: false};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var popupOpenBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup]');

    popupOpenBtn.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.setState({
          opened: true
        });
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: this is the button, console.log(this)

Comment: NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I get to Popup and change state for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler is scoped to the button, not to the class. Try this instead:

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {opened: false};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var popupOpenBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup]');
    var component = this;

    popupOpenBtn.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        component.setState({
          opened: true
        });
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: In this situation I have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. So here *this* is not my component